# How to loop the input fields data in nested from to an array in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

Actually I need to show the data in an Array in this format after form validation. Please anyone help me out I'm new to angular js.

```
$scope.newuser=[
{
    "EmployeeID": "A123",
    "FullName": "phantommm",
    "UserRegistrationDate": "2015-07-10T00:00:00",
    "LastActiveDate": "2015-07-10T00:00:00",
    "UserProjects": [
        {
            "UserID": 1,
            "ProjectID": 1,
            "ProjectRoleID": 2,
            "IsAccepted": true
        },
        {
            "UserID": 1,
            "ProjectID": 2,
            "ProjectRoleID": 3,
            "IsAccepted": true
        }
    ]
},
{
    "EmployeeID": "A123",
    "FullName": "phantommm",
    "UserRegistrationDate": "2015-07-10T00:00:00",
    "LastActiveDate": "2015-07-10T00:00:00",
    "UserProjects": [
        {
            "UserID": 2,
            "ProjectID": 1,
            "ProjectRoleID": 2,
            "IsAccepted": true
        }
    ]
}
```

]

But i'm getting the data in this format,

```
$scope.newuser=[
{
    "EmployeeID": "A123",
    "FullName": "phantommm",
    "UserRegistrationDate": "2015-07-10T00:00:00",
    "LastActiveDate": "2015-07-10T00:00:00",
    "UserID": 1,
    "ProjectID": 1,
    "ProjectRoleID": 2,
    "IsAccepted": true
},
{
    "EmployeeID": "A12345",
    "FullName": "phantommm123",
    "UserRegistrationDate": "2015-07-10T00:00:00",
    "LastActiveDate": "2015-07-10T00:00:00",
    "UserID": 2,
    "ProjectID": 1,
    "ProjectRoleID": 3,
    "IsAccepted": true
}
```

]

I'm Using this code for getting the data from form,

```
   myapp.controller('mainController', function ($scope) {         
    $scope.submitForm = function() {
    $scope.newuser = [];
    $scope.submitted = true;
    $scope.counter = 1;
    $scope.counter++;
if ($scope.userForm.$valid) {

         $scope.newuser.push({ 
                          UserID            :  $scope.counter,
                          EmployeeID        :  $scope.user.employeeid,
                          FullName          :  $scope.user.fname, 
                          UserPassword      :  $scope.user.confirmPassword,
                          EmailID           :  $scope.user.email,
                          Mobile            :  $scope.user.phone,
                          SecurityQuestionID :  $scope.user.secutyqquestn,
                          SecurityAnswer    :  $scope.user.secutyanswer,                            
                          id                :   $scope.counter,                        
                          ctpjct            : $scope.user.curntpjct,
                          pos               : $scope.user.positio                             
                        })                  

            alert('Registration Succesfully Completed'); 

} else {
          alert('Invalid Fields')
}
```

};
  });

Comment: it's normal that you are guetting this structure, because you push all the data to the same level.. You should have : $scope.user.userprojects.push({           "UserID": $scope.counter,
            "ProjectID": $scope.user.currentpjct,
            "ProjectRoleID": $scope.user.role,
            "IsAccepted":$scope.user.status})

Comment: Thank U so much. It's Working...@MayK